# How to convert binary string to utf8?

Tags: php, binary, ffi

I'm playing around with FFI and trying to read `sapi_request_info.request_method` from memory. As a result, I get a binary string like this - `b"\x05\x1F\x7F"`. How can I convert this to a normal utf8 string? Thank you.

Comment: If it's not text, it doesn't make sense to convert it to UTF-8.

Comment: `\x05\x1F\x7F` isn't binary. Those are control characters, there is no visual representation for them.